# Change ternary operation into if-else statement

Tags: c

I just started learning C, and I have some problems with the `? :` operator.

How can I change

```
x = c ? a : b;
```

into an if else statement?

```
if() { x=a; }  else { x=b;}
```

Is it correct like this? I don't know what the condition should be.

Comment: The conditional operator is beautiful in that it doesn't allow mutation, just return of a value of the same type from more than one branch. Why the need to change to an if statement?

Comment: I was just interested how it works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A turnary statement is in the form:

```
result = (booleanValue ? valueA : valueB);
```

This converts to:

```
if (booleanValue) {
    result = valueA;
} else {
    result = valueB;
}
```

In your case "booleanValue" is "c", "valueA" is "a", "valueB" is "b". Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It would be

```
if(c)
   x=a;
else
   x=b;
```

Comment: thank's. I think it confused me that there was no condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent `if` statement:

```
if (c)
{
    x = a;
}
else
{
    x = b;
}
```

The conditional operator `?:` is described in chapter 2.11 of your C book, "The C Programming Language", 2nd edition, by Kernighan and Ritchie.